# ggplot styles in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, ipython

When I look at the [plotting style in the Pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/visualization.html), the plots look different from the default one. It seems to mimic the ggplot "look and feel".

Same thing with the [seaborn's package](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/examples/plotting_distributions.ipynb).

How can I load that style? (even if I am not using a notebook?)

Comment: to get the seaborn styling, just add `import seaborn` to the top of the script/notebook/whatever (assumes you have seaborn installed)

Comment: I would point out nicer is rather subjective.  I can't be the only person who finds the ggplot style hideous.  There is also a `matplotlib.style` module which will be in 1.4 that will give style-sheet like capability.

Comment: @tcaswell I agree (that it is subjective) I changed the OP.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Update:** If you have matplotlib >= 1.4, there is a new `style` module which has a `ggplot` style by default. To activate this, use:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
```

To see all the available styles, you can check `plt.style.available`.

---

Similarly, for seaborn styling you can do:

```
plt.style.use('seaborn-white')
```

or, you can use `seaborn`'s own machinery to set up the styling:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
```

The `set()` function has more options to select a specific style (see [`docs`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set.html#seaborn.set)). Note that `seaborn` previously did the above automatically on import, but with the latest versions (>= 0.8) this is no longer the case.

---

If you actually want a ggplot-like syntax in Python as well (and not only the styling), take a look at the [`plotnine`](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package, which is a grammar of graphics implementation in Python with a syntax very similar to R's ggplot2.

---

Note: the old answer mentioned to do `pd.options.display.mpl_style = 'default'`
. This was however deprecated in pandas in favor of matplotlib's styling using `plt.style(..)`, and in the meantime this functionality is even removed from pandas.

Comment: The themes from the plotnine package can be easily used with matplotlib as in my answer below.

Comment: @joris, What are the perks of using seaborn's own machinery to set up the styling?

Answer (score 5):

For the themes in python-ggplot, you can use them with other plots:

```python
from ggplot import theme_gray
theme = theme_gray()
with mpl.rc_context():
    mpl.rcParams.update(theme.get_rcParams())

    # plotting commands here

    for ax in plt.gcf().axes:
        theme.post_plot_callback(ax)
```

Comment: This is a good approach, but the ggplot project appears dead.  One can try using the [plotnine](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library.

Comment: In plotnine, `theme.get_rcParams()` is now `theme.rcParams` and an additional `theme.setup_figure(figure)` before plotting and afterwards instead of the `theme.post_plot_callback()`you now probably have to do multiple calls to `theme.apply_figure(fig)` (for the figure object) and `theme.apply(ax)` (iterating over all axis objects in the figure).

Answer (score 5):

If you need to see available styles :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print(plt.style.available)
```

This will print available styles.

And use this link to select the style you prefer

https://tonysyu.github.io/raw_content/matplotlib-style-gallery/gallery.html

Answer (score 1):

Jan Katins's answer is good, but the python-ggplot project seems to have become inactive.  The plotnine project is more developed and supports an analogous, but superficially different, solution:

```
from plotnine import theme_bw
import matplotlib as mpl
theme = theme_bw()

with mpl.rc_context():
    mpl.rcParams.update(theme.rcParams)
```

Comment: this ruined my plot fonts!

Answer (score 0):

While I think that [joris answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22543333/1623829) is a better solution since you're using Pandas, it should be mentioned that Matplotlib can be set to mimic ggplot by issuing the command `matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')`.

See examples in the [Matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html#style_sheets).