# Scatterplot without linear fit in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am wondering if there is a way to turn off the linear fit in seaborn's `lmplot` or if there is an equivalent function that just produces the scatterplot. 
Sure, I could also use matplotlib, however, I find the syntax and aesthetics in seaborn quite appealing. E.g,. I want to plot the following plot

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="ticks")

df = sns.load_dataset("anscombe")
sns.lmplot("x", "y", data=df, hue='dataset')
```

[image]

Without the linear fit like so:

```
from itertools import cycle
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

color_gen = cycle(('blue', 'lightgreen', 'red', 'purple', 'gray', 'cyan'))

for lab in np.unique(df['dataset']):
    plt.scatter(df.loc[df['dataset'] == lab, 'x'], 
                df.loc[df['dataset'] == lab, 'y'], 
                c=next(color_gen),
                label=lab)

plt.legend(loc='best')
```

[image]

Comment: Several approaches with pandas and seaborn styles [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22543208/ggplot-styles-in-python) -- you can use seaborn plotting as a context while working in matplotlib, for instance.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

set `fit_reg` argument to `False`:

```
sns.lmplot("x", "y", data=df, hue='dataset', fit_reg=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer the question, but may help others who find there way here who just want to do a plain old scatter plot.
[As of version 0.9.0](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html#v0-9-0-july-2018) seaborn now has a [`scatterplot` method](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html#seaborn-scatterplot).

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="ticks")

df = sns.load_dataset("anscombe")
sns.scatterplot("x", "y", data=df, hue='dataset')
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I recommend instead of `sns.lmplot()` to use `sns.scatterplot()`

```
# import libaries
import seaborn as sns

# load tips dataset from GitHub seaborn repository
tips_df = sns.load_dataset("tips")

#create scatter plot
sns.scatterplot(x = "tip", y = "total_bill", data = tips_df, hue ="sex")
```

To learn more in detail follow [seaborn scatter plot](https://indianaiproduction.com/seaborn-scatter-plot) using sns.scatterplot() tutorial