# Plotting numpy array using Seaborn

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, machine-learning, seaborn

I'm using python 2.7. I know this will be very basic, however I'm really confused and I would like to have a better understanding of seaborn.

I have two numpy arrays `X` and `y` and I'd like to use Seaborn to plot them.

Here is my `X` numpy array:

```
[[ 1.82716998 -1.75449225]
 [ 0.09258069  0.16245259]
 [ 1.09240926  0.08617436]]
```

And here is the `y` numpy array:

```
[ 1. -1.  1. ]
```

How can I successfully plot my data points taking into account the class label from the `y` array?

Thank you,

Comment: Can you also add how you want the X & Y to be correlated and what X means? X array has shape of 2 x 3 values. These 2 things in array are x, y coordinates? How to display the Y values? Would you like a scatter plot?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use seaborn functions to plot graphs. Do dir(sns) to see all the plots. Here is your output in `sns.scatterplot`. You can check the api docs [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) or example code with plots [here](https://python-graph-gallery.com/40-basic-scatterplot-seaborn/)

```
import seaborn as sns 
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[ 1.82716998, -1.75449225],
 [ 0.09258069,  0.16245259],
 [ 1.09240926,  0.08617436]], columns=["x", "y"])

df["val"] = pd.Series([1, -1, 1]).apply(lambda x: "red" if x==1 else "blue")


sns.scatterplot(df["x"], df["y"], c=df["val"]).plot()
```

Gives

[image]
Is this the exact input output you wanted?

You can do it with pyplot, just importing seaborn changes pyplot color and plot scheme

```
import seaborn as sns 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df = pd.DataFrame([[ 1.82716998, -1.75449225],
 [ 0.09258069,  0.16245259],
 [ 1.09240926,  0.08617436]], columns=["x", "y"])
df["val"] = pd.Series([1, -1, 1]).apply(lambda x: "red" if x==1 else "blue")
ax.scatter(x=df["x"], y=df["y"], c=df["val"])
plt.plot()
```

Here is a [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637150/scatterplot-without-linear-fit-in-seaborn) of doing the same with sns.lmplot

Comment: Thank you this worked. I think it does what I want now it's my task to go back to the features and investigate. Thank you!! The second example causes this error: 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'scatterplot'

Comment: Please note that my data don't have commas as seperators

Comment: Just use X and Y instead of the arrays, no need for comma as seperators, pd.DataFrame has option to set delimiter.

Comment: sns.scatterplot is a valid function, I added the api doc for it.

Comment: it looks like it's a new feature added in 0.9.0. Can you give an example of sns.(function) from 0.8.0. I tried the other post solution it gave TypeError: lmplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'c'

Comment: Here is the api of lmplot from seaborn 0.8.1 https://web.archive.org/web/20171230053852/http://seaborn.pydata.org:80/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html#seaborn.lmplot It has examples of using the data attribute directly to color the plot using the DataFrame. See `g = sns.lmplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="smoker", data=tips,palette=dict(Yes="g", No="m"))` 
If you use the pyplot version of my answer, you will be able to plot on `ax` object multiple times. So you can plot scatter once with a dataframe view using df.loc[predicate, "column"] in one color, and plot on it again with another color.